# Find an example of $0\to A\to B\to C\to 0$ and $M$ such that $\mathrm{Hom}_R(B,M)\to\mathrm{Hom}_R(A,M)$ is not surjective

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, exact-sequence

Let $R$ be a commutative ring with unity. Let
$$
0\to A\stackrel{f}{\to} B\stackrel{g}{\to} C\to 0
$$
be an exact sequence of $R$-modules. This induces an exact sequence for each $R$-module $M$:
$$
0\to\mathrm{Hom}_R(C,M)\stackrel{\bar{g}}{\to}\mathrm{Hom}_R(B,M)\stackrel{\bar f}{\to}\mathrm{Hom}_R(A,M),
$$
here $\bar f$ sends $h$ to $h\circ f$ and $\bar g$ is similarly defined.

Question:

> Find an example of $0\to A\to B\to C\to 0$ and $M$ such that $\mathrm{Hom}_R(B,M)\to\mathrm{Hom}_R(A,M)$ is not surjective.

---

Up to isomorphisms, we can just consider $0\to A\stackrel{f}{\to} B\stackrel{g}{\to} B/A\to 0$, where $A$ is a submodule of $B$, and $f$, $g$ are natural homomorphisms. This simplifies the problem a little bit but I am still not sure how to find such an example.

Comment: $A=\mathbb Z, B=\mathbb Q, M=\mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z.$

Comment: Or, for a different  (or maybe not different) flavor: $A =B=M={\mathbb Z}$, with $f(x) = 2x$. Then the identity on $A$ is not the restriction of any homomorphism $\lambda$ from $B$ to $M$. For, if it were,  $\lambda(2) =1$, which would force $\lambda(1) =1/2 \not\in M$ (contradiction).